# Read resources dir

Tags: spring-boot, java-stream

The code below permits reading a /demo directory when deployed to localhost w/o a context-path, with the /demo directly off the project root.   [image: project view]

```
Path demoDirPath = Paths.get(context.getContextPath(), demoDir);
        Iterator<Path> contents=demoDirPath.iterator();
        HashSet<Path> jsonFiles = new HashSet<>();
        try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(demoDirPath)) {
            jsonFiles = (HashSet<Path>) stream
                    .filter(file -> !Files.isDirectory(file) && file.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".json")
                            && file.getFileName().toString().contains(transType)
                    )
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
```

However for war deployment the /demo is not accessible and does not fail just jsonFiles.size()==0.  Then /demo is placed in /resources/demo and with a context-path.  I tried the second code snippet below and the resource is null.  How can I read the /demo in actual context-path based deployment, please?

```
String folder ="classpath:/resources/demo";
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        URL resource = classLoader.getResource(folder);
        try {
            List<File> collect = Files.walk(Paths.get(resource.toURI()))
                    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                    .map(x -> x.toFile())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Comment: You cannot as it isn't a file resource in the sense of `java.util.File`. a `java.util.File` needs to be a physical resource on disk **not** a file or directory in a jar/war.

Comment: However it is in the war and expanded on deployment under /resources.  Also it works deployed to localhost.

Comment: It isn't under `/resources` as that is the classpath. You don't want to add or that people can read your classpath (that is a security risk).

Comment: This is demo data I need to read and process it.  It works on localhost I need to access it from a deployed context-path so putting it in resources I interpreted as being like an image for a page just used differently.  How can I achiever my usecase?

Comment: It works on localhost (running from the main I assume) because that isn't from inside a jar. As stated what you try to do is not possible from a jar/war location. You are doing a directory listing which won't work. If you know the full path to the resource you can just read it butyou cannot list it!.

Comment: Okay the /demo is off classes deployed.  What syntax and which approach is best to use read in the directory contents?